# How to modify Matplot chart intervals in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

In Python, I am pulling in data from a data frame that should show me the number of COVID-19 cases by date. See example values for three dates:

date: 20201201; positive: 10000

date: 20201202; positive: 10500

date: 20201203; positive: 11000

I am hitting a roadblock when I try to format the plot I created. How can I increase the font of the x and y axes and modify the intervals so that instead of each individual date being shown, I can show the only first day of every month? Note that "date" is currently listed as an object and "positive" is listed as int64.

Also, what does the 121 represent in my code? I picked this up from somewhere else and noticed whenever I change the number, I get an error.

Thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = data["date"]
y = data["positive"]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(75, 25))

# Adds subplot on position 1
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)

ax.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: convert `data['date']` to datetime type: `data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])` then use [MonthLocator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator).

Answer (score 0):

plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=10) # for the label

plt.xticks(fontsize=10) # for the tick values

Also suggest using Seaborn library for plotting data, relatively straightforward than Matplotlib

Quick resource as example : https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html